How to add pricing per minute to my agora or zegocloud based video chatting web app
I am using zegocloud to build an video chatting service, an i want to add an functionality of per minute pricing to my video call,
For ex: if my pricing is 1$ per minute and user have 10$ in their wallet then after 10 mins of call the call should automatically end and wallet balance should be updated to 0$.
Any idea how to approach this logic ??
I am nkt able to navigate through this problem, so any help would be very helpful
